# Numpy - calculate length of non-interrupted row in center of matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for a fast, computationally efficient, manner to calculate, in a matrix, the length of the non-interrupted series of "1"'s that have a “1” at the center of the matrix (e.g. column 5 in the example per below). In the example code per below – the desired answer would be 3,4,5,6. My actual matrices have many times more rows and columns, so I am especially looking for a way to do this in a computationally efficient manner.  Any suggestion much appreciated.

```
from numpy import *
a = array([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0])
a=a.reshape(4,9)
```

Comment: Can we assume that the matrix always has an odd number of columns?

Comment: yes - we can assume this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neglecting the boundary cases when either or both halves might be full of `1s` or `0s`, here's one approach using `slicing` to select the two halves and then `argmin()` to detect those shifts from `1` to `0` -

```
# Get middle col ID
n = (a.shape[1]+1)//2

# Get non-interrupted length from middle col to left and right and add up
lens = a[:,n:].argmin(1)+a[:,n-1::-1].argmin(1)
```

Including the boundary cases would probably involve using bunch of if-else to check whether those indices from `argmin` are indeed `0`'s.

Sample run -

```
In [60]: a
Out[60]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

In [61]: n = (a.shape[1]+1)//2

In [62]: a[:,n:].argmin(1)+a[:,n-1::-1].argmin(1)
Out[62]: array([3, 4, 5, 6])
```